# click() not working with xpath selector

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, ui-automation, nightwatch.js

I am new to UI testing and using Nightwatch. I'm unsuccessfully trying to click an element selected with xpath. It seems like a simple case, the element is asserted as visible, but it's not being clicked.

**css:**

```
<a class="blabla" href="/xx/000/aaa">
  <div class="action-button__inner">Open This</div>
</a>
```

**selector:**

```
openThis: {
      selector: '//div[text()="Open This"]',
      locateStrategy: 'xpath'
    }
```

**command:**

```
.waitForElementVisible('@openThis', 2000)
.click('@openThis');
```

**output:**

```
  ✔ Element <//div[text()="Open This"]> was visible after 74 milliseconds.
```

BUT, it's not clicking on it, so the following assertions fail. All help would be appreciated! Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Can you paste your DOM?

Comment: I've solved the issue adding click() twice. For some reason it just skips the first click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.click()` is not responding sometimes. `waitForElementClickable` didn't work.

Using twice `.click() .click()` is ugly but does the job.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using waitForElementVisible property try using  waitForElementClickable